# Trie in C. Recursive Insertion improper working

Tags: c

Below is my implementation of recursive functions to insert words into trie and to search through it. The problem is with inserting which is not working well. For example when passing word "on" to SearchWord() I get back "Found" but for any other words it is "NotFound". I know there should be free() of memory at the end of main() but first I wanted to focus on correct implementation of the insertion. May somebody look through the code, especially through InsertIntoTrie() function and explain to me the reason of its failure working?
I suppose the problem is with this function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

//declaration of struct TrieNode
typedef struct TrieNode
{
    struct TrieNode* Children[27];
    bool endOfWord;
}
TrieNode;

//declaration of Root
TrieNode* Root = NULL;

//Recursive inserting word into the trie
void InsertIntoTrie(TrieNode* current, char* word, int index)
{
    if(index == strlen(word))
    {
        current -> endOfWord = true;
        return;
    }
    int ch = ((word[index] == '\'') ? 26 : (word[index] - 97));
    //printf("%d\n", ch);
    if(current -> Children[ch] == NULL)
    {
        current -> Children[ch] = (TrieNode*) malloc(sizeof(TrieNode));
        current = current -> Children[ch];
    }
    InsertIntoTrie(current, word, index + 1);
}

void InsertWord(char* word)
{   
    Root = (TrieNode*) malloc(sizeof(TrieNode));
    InsertIntoTrie(Root, word, 0);
}

//Recursive search into trie
bool SearchIntoTrie(TrieNode* current, char* word, int index)
{
    if (index == strlen(word))
    {
        return current -> endOfWord;
    }
    int ch = ((word[index] == '\'') ? 26 : (tolower(word[index]) - 97));
    //printf("search[%d] = %d\n", index, ch);
    current = current -> Children[ch];
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //printf("search[%d] = %d\n", index, ch);
    return SearchIntoTrie(current, word, index + 1);
}


bool SearchWord(char* word)
{
    return SearchIntoTrie(Root, word, 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    //File declaration for testing
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");
    fputs("alice\nwas\nbeg''inning\nto\nget\nvery\ntired\nof\nsitting\nby\nher\nsister\non\n", fp);
    rewind(fp);

    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        InsertWord(word);
        //printf("next word\n");
    }

    SearchWord("was") ? printf("Found\n") : printf("NotFound\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect any of the elements of `Children` would be `NULL` if you never initialize them?

Comment: Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should not be written with spaces on either side.

Comment: I'm a newbie, I know this code is still in many ways incorrect. Can you give me some hint how to initialize them? Should I use a loop for assigning 'NULL' to every 'Children' ??

Comment: Simplest is to use `calloc()`. Otherwise a loop is good.  Since you've got two places where you allocate a node that should be initialized, write a function to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Your "InsertWord" function is allocating a new TrieNode at every call. As suggested in the comments you will also need to initialize the memory:

```
Root = (TrieNode*) malloc(sizeof(TrieNode));
```

should be:

```
if(Root == NULL)
    Root = (TrieNode*) calloc(1, sizeof(TrieNode));
```

Comment: Additionally, the memory for the newly allocated node should be initialized